# Formating an input field to accept 0, 0.1 and negative numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I want the input below to accept $0, $0.01, and negative values but no luck. Any ideas ? It will be nice to keep the commas if it a million.

```
        <div className="form-group has-validation col-xs-12">
            <label htmlFor="NetWorth">Net Worth</label>
            <input
                className="form-control text-right"
                id="NetWorth"
                maxLength="16"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    let strippedFloat = parseInt(e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ''));
                    dispatchCustomer({ type: "INPUTCHANGED", key: "netWorth", value: !!strippedFloat ? strippedFloat : null })
                }}
                value={customer.netWorth ?
                    new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: "USD", maximumFractionDigits: 0 }).format(customer.netWorth) :
                    ""}
            />    
        </div>
```